# Lookup on a pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lookup

here is a basic problem of lookup but after some research, I didn't found the answer :

A starting DF

```
   id  anc  anc1  anc2  anc3  anc4  anc5  anc6
0   1    2   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0.5   0.6
1   2    1   0.3   0.4   0.6   0.4   0.5   0.6
2   3    2   0.2   0.4   0.7   0.4   0.6   0.6
3   4    3   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.4   0.2   0.3
```

What I want is to create with a for loop 3 new columns lap1-lap3.
For the first row lap1 will be equal to the value of anc2 because anc=2, lap2 = anc3 (corresponding to anc+1),lap3=anc4
For row 2, lap1 = anc1 because anc=1, ...

The DF I want to obtain is the following

```
   id  anc  anc1  anc2  anc3  anc4  anc5  anc6  lap1  lap2  lap3
0   1    2   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0.5   0.6   0.2   0.3   0.4
1   2    1   0.3   0.4   0.6   0.4   0.5   0.6   0.3   0.4   0.6
2   3    4   0.2   0.4   0.7   0.4   0.6   0.6   0.4   0.7   0.4
3   4    3   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.4   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.4   0.2
```

Thks for any help

Comment: lap1 for row 1 is 0.6. is that correct?

Comment: No, lap1 for row 1 equal 0.2 because anc=2 for this row so I put the value of anc2

Comment: I meant row2, but I see you have made the corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pandas wide to long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) to reshape the data, then calculate for each of the rows, where you compare the `indexer` with the `num` :

```
box = pd.wide_to_long(
    #give a different name to 'anc',
    #to avoid name collision
    df.rename(columns={"anc": "indexer"}),
    stubnames=["anc"],
    i=["id", "indexer"],
    j="num",
)

#here we get the rows that match in increasing fashion
df["lap1"] = box.query("indexer == num")["anc"].array
df["lap2"] = box.query("indexer + 1 == num")["anc"].array
df["lap3"] = box.query("indexer + 2 == num")["anc"].array
```

Update : You can use a for loop to get the results for the columns dynamically:

```
for num in range(1, 4):
    df[f"lap{num}"] = box.query("indexer + @num-1  == num")["anc"].array
```

Of course you can change the `range` to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for you're answer, but what if I need to do that until lap100 ? Is there a way to pass the last lines into a for loop ?

Comment: alright. gimme a minute to find something more generic